# Can't resolve symbol 'SecondActivity' Validates resource references inside Android XML files

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Application development. I just added another activity tag in my AndroidManifest.xml file but its gives me the following message : Can't resolve symbol 'SecondActivity' Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

I want to know why is this message getting displayed?

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aupadhyay.myfirstapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/amiticon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="anything" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my SecondActivity.java file :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

}
```

Picture : 
[image]

Comment: are you sure your `SecondActivity` belongs to `"com.aupadhyay.myfirstapp"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

- Remove the intent-filter inside your second activity unless you really need that.
- In your second activity, override onCreate method

  ```
  @override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.second_activity_layout);
   }
  ```

Did you create a layout for your second activity? It seems your activity is empty - although this might not be the cause of your problem. Also what is the location of your SecondActivity, a different package or in the same place as the first activity?

As shown in your code, your second activity doesn't seem to have any of that layout stuff!

I hope this helps you!

Comment: it gives `missing method body, or declare abstract` also it gives `can't resolve symbol second_activity_layout`

Comment: okay, thanks... but the problem was that the file `SecondActivity.java` was under  androidTest package, Shifting file to the package of `MainActivity` removes the message.

Comment: So was this answer helpful to you?

Comment: Ohh !! I didn't notice your *Did you create* part before adding an answer, If I was aware of that, I would support your answer, But still 1 up.

Comment: Thanks, no problem at all!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `SecondActivity` doesn't belongs to the package `"com.aupadhyay.myfirstapp"`, So move it to `src` of the `"com.aupadhyay.myfirstapp"` package where ever it currently belongs to.